# Remove operation on iterator not allowed in CopyOnWriteArrayLIst

Tags: java, collections

I am a beginner in Collections framework and came across this concept in CopyOnWriteArrayList:

```
the remove() operation on the returned Iterator is not permitted – resulting with UnsupportedOperationException. However the remove() method of the CopyOnWriteArrayList itself is permitted.
```

I am aware that for each mutation a copy of the underlying list is created but I am not sure why the above scenario is not permitted.Can anyone explain the reason why is this so?

Comment: When you create a new iterator, the current copy is used. Modifying that copy will possibly change other iterators that work on the same copy.

Comment: Wont the same thing happen using the list's own remove method as well?

Comment: That is true but List and Iterators are different objects. The list is under no obligation to make sure iterator is consistent while iterator has to make sure it is consistent. If you call remove on the list while the iterator is ongoing, you run the risk of some strange behavior there as well but you are supposed to take care of that.

Comment: The CopyOnWriteArrayList will take care that the iterator is not affected by it.